# Given a circle and an external point, find the x intercept of the line tangent to the circle and goes through the point.

Tags: circles, tangent-line

The equation of the circle is given by $x^2+(y-r)^2=r^2$ where $r$ is the radius. The point is located at the point $(d,h)$.

Here is my approach to this: the general equation of all lines that passes through the point can be written as $y=m(x-d)+h$, and the equation of the circle is $y=\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}+r$. So I equate them to each other and simplify to get a quadratic equation like this:
$$m(x-d)+h=\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}+r$$
$$(m^2+1)x^2+2m(h-r-md)x+(m^2d^2-2mdh+2mdr+h^2-2hr)=0$$
Since the line is tangent to the circle, I set the discriminant to zero and solve for $m$.
$$[2m(h-r-md)]^2-4(m^2+1)(m^2d^2-3mdh+2mdr+h^2-2hr)=0$$
This simplifies to:
$$(r^2-d^2)m^2+2d(h-r)m+(2hr-h^2)=0$$
Using the quadratic equation:
$$m=\frac{-d(h-r)\pm r\sqrt{d^2-2hr+h^2}}{r^2-d^2}$$
Now putting this back into the line equation $y=m(x-d)+h$, the x-intercept is found by setting y equal to zero, I found x to be:
$$x=d+\frac{h(r^2-d^2)}{d(h-r)\pm r\sqrt{d^2-2hr+r^2}}$$
I have verified this by plugging in values, but as you can see this is very messy, I am just wondering if there is a clean and easier way to do this.

Comment: A tangent has the distance $r$ to the center of the circle. By using vectors this gives a simpler Ansatz me think. But in the end there are two solutions.

Comment: The polar equation of the circle is $\rho = 2r\sin\theta$. You might investigate whether the problem might be solved that way.

Comment: The explanation given in this problem should help with figuring out the equation of the tangent line, based on the angle of the circle's radius (which is perpendicular to the tangent). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4870684/calculating-angle-for-line-tangent-to-circle-through-a-point

Answer (score 0):

For a circle $X^2+Y^2=R^2$ the equation of line tangent at $(X_1,Y_1)$ is given by $$(X_1)X+(Y_1)Y=R^2$$

In your question $$X=x,Y=y-r,R=r$$

Put the values and you get the equation of line from which X intercept can be found.

Comment: Only _line_? Why not line**s** (plural)?

Comment: Yes, but how would I figure out the coordinates of point of tangency?

Comment: @m-stgt $(X_1,Y_1)$ lies on the circle. Hence only one tangent can be drawn

Comment: @RaymondLi  I thought that $(d,h)$ was on the circle. Since it is not, your answer will stay messy as no other conditions are given. There is no simpler form.

Comment: @Aarush Saharan -- Headline states _"Given a circle and an external point"_, and I took this for real ;)

Comment: Sorry I missed that

Comment: @Raymond Li -- try this for now:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_analytische_Geometrie

Comment: The name of this line is the *polar* of the point: $$\langle x^2+y^2-r(y+y),xd+yh-r(y+h)\rangle.$$ The messy quadratic formula solution is: $$(x,y)=\\
(\frac{dr^2-r(r-h)\sqrt{d^2+h^2-2hr}}{(h-r)^2+d^2},\frac{((h^2+d^2)r-hr^2)-rd\sqrt{d^2+h^2-2hr}}{(h-r)^2+d^2}),\\(\frac{dr^2+r(r-h)\sqrt{d^2+h^2-2hr}}{(h-r)^2+d^2},\frac{((h^2+d^2)r-hr^2)+rd\sqrt{d^2+h^2-2hr}}{(h-r)^2+d^2}.$$