# Calculating angle for line tangent to circle through a point

Tags: trigonometry, tangent-line

I have a circle of fixed radius $r$. I have a target that is $x$ units laterally separated from the center of the circle, and $y$ units vertically. I need to calculate the angle $θ$ which is the declination of the radius that connects that target to the upper tangent on the circle.

[image: visual depiction of the above, with the line connecting the origin to the target labeled as 'h']

It feels like there should be  a simpler formula than what I've shown in the diagram:

$$θ=180° - tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) - cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right)$$

Is there a way to simplify this calculation further?

Comment: In your formula, sin-1 should be corrected to tan-1. For a simpler formula, note that the quadrilateral is cyclic, therefore the angle theta you are looking for is equal to the angle at point T (target).

Comment: @ACB Thank you! I definitely made a mistake with sin/tan; I've updated my question and image with the correction. I didn't understand your second sentence; you say "the angle at point T", but…the angle of what line with respect to which other line?

Comment: The acute angle between green segment and dashed line=theta.

Comment: See here: https://www.geogebra.org/m/mM92cFJr